# $.getJSON fails on a successful http request

Tags: javascript, http, jquery

I'm calling the method in my page:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred(
    $.getJSON(serviceAddress)
        .done(function (result, status) {
            bo.BusinessObject.DtosToaKoArray(result, resultList);
            dfd.resolve(resultList);
        })
        .fail(function (result, status) {
            logger.logError(result);
            dfd.reject(result);
        }));

return dfd;
```

After calling the JSON, the firebug shows that HttpRequest was successfull and the response header is like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcV29ya3NwYWNlc1xNZWhyYW5cSW5mcmFzdHJ1Y3R1cmVcTWFpblxTb3VyY2VcSW5mcmFzdHJ1Y3R1cmVcU291cmNlXENhcmFuZS5HYWxheHkuV2ViQXBpXGFwaVxEYXRhUHJvdmlkZXJcTGlzdFNlcnZpY2Vc?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 04 Aug 2013 05:57:39 GMT
Content-Length: 6684
```

but the problem is that instead of `done` callback, the `fail` callback is called with this result:

```
Object { readyState=4, status=404, statusText="error"}
```

What is wrong about my call that fails the successful http request?

**Edit1.**

My website (MyApp.Web) is on localhost:2771 and the calling service is in another project (MyApp.WebApi) on the localhost:4143

Comment: what is your expected response, some server code please ?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I've removed the deferred part totally and just called the `getJSON` part. but the problem still remains.

Comment: @Hemant_Negi I expect the `done` function to call (as it is a successful response) and the result would be the returned json.

Comment: the header is displaying content length 6684 bytes and the displayed response is surly not that.
Are you sure your json response in correct format.

Comment: @Hemant_Negi I've checked the returned Json showing in the browser. It was ok. When I go to `http://localhost:4143/api/DataProvider/ListService/?listTypeName=Module` using browser it shows the correct json. but the firebug shows nothing in the response tab (while its status is ok)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski there's no XHR with 404 in the firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely run into some hurdles trying to make cross-origin requests. [That includes port-to-port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The solutions also depend on the service and what features it supports.

- [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (or, JSON with Padding)

  The service would need to accept a `callback` and output the JSON wrapped in a function call:

  ```
  // http://...?callback=completeRequest
  completeRequest(["json", "data"]);
  ```

  The parameter can be a different name than `callback`. But, you can instruct jQuery to use it by including a placeholder parameter (`...=?`):

  ```
  $.getJSON(serviceAddress + "?callback=?")
  ```

  This can also be used in any browser as it's requested as a `<script src>` and the JSON will be parsed as [JavaScript literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals).
- [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

  The service will need to support [preflight, `OPTIONS` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) and respond with [`Access-Control-Allow-*` headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers).

  Also, while [most current browsers support CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), this can be limited if you need to support older editions.

Otherwise, you'll need to create a proxy destination in your application (`localhost:2771`) that makes the cross-origin request server-side to the service (`localhost:4143`).

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. I just used `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` from http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Answer (score 0):

It might not be finding your target page and that's why you might be getting a 404 in your result object. Make sure that your serviceAddress is correct.

In addition to that When you specify: `dataType: 'json'` jQuery will fire the error event if the response cannot be parsed as JSON(despite the 200 reply). Make sure that the data returned from the server is valid JSON, you might want to validate the structure manually via [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

It might be any of these 2 problems.

Comment: As I said the firebug shows that the call was successful, so nothing is wrong about the `serviceAddress`.

Comment: The json format is ok. But some point that might relate. my website is on `localhost:2771` and the calling service is in another project on the `localhost:4143`